# WCF Service - MTOM Security modes & transport/message property's values

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, mtom

Could you please let me know, how/what to set the Mode and ClientCredentialType property in configuration for **MTOM-basicHttpBinding**.

For **ANONYMOUS** authentication-  Below configuration is working fine

```
<security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```

Could you please help me to understand what should the values against each attribute for **NTLM and Windows** authentication types for **Mtom** binding?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the below security modes support `Windows/NTLM` authentication and MTOM encoding.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://localhost:21011");
  BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom;
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
            // NTLM
            //binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
```

Or,

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:21011");
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom;
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.